# AppFabric - Putting Data into Local Cache

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

I'm pretty new to AppFabric and what I'm trying to understand is how to stipulate that I want data to go into the Distributed cache as well as the Local Cache

I read the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963103/using-a-mix-of-appfabric-local-cache-and-server-cache) which is doing this based on config.  I am not using any XML config but rather creating my objects with configuration programmatically.  I am playing around with the following code:-

```
// Declare array for cache host(s).

List<DataCacheServerEndpoint> servers = new List<DataCacheServerEndpoint>();
servers.Add(new DataCacheServerEndpoint("SERVER1", 10023));
servers.Add(new DataCacheServerEndpoint("SERVER2", 10023));
servers.Add(new DataCacheServerEndpoint("SERVER3", 10023));

DataCacheLocalCacheProperties localCacheConfig;
TimeSpan localTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);

localCacheConfig = new DataCacheLocalCacheProperties(10000, localTimeout, DataCacheLocalCacheInvalidationPolicy.TimeoutBased);


// Setup the DataCacheFactory configuration.
DataCacheFactoryConfiguration factoryConfig = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
factoryConfig.Servers = servers;
factoryConfig.SecurityProperties = new DataCacheSecurity(DataCacheSecurityMode.None, DataCacheProtectionLevel.None);

factoryConfig.LocalCacheProperties = localCacheConfig;

DataCacheFactory factory = DataCacheFactoryExtensions.Create(factoryConfig);
DataCache dataCache = factory.GetCache("MyCache");

dataCache.Put("myKey", "MyValue");
```

Am I right to assume that because I have added the local cache config to the factoryConfig object that my cached item will be automatically added to local cache as well as the distributed cache?

And therefore if I want items only cached to distributed cache do I just need to drop off adding the local cache config to the factoryConfig object?

Or do I need two separate factory config objects - one for each cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790983%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) that, yes, the object will be stored in the local cache, if the local cache is enabled:

> When local cache is enabled, the cache client stores a reference to the object locally.

The [instructions for "enabling the local cache"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790857%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) are exactly as you've done -- basically just using the `DataCacheLocalCacheProperties` (although the local cache can also be enabled using [app.config settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790880%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) instead).

So it's exactly as you say -- to use the distributed cache only, without the local, then use a `DataCache` object taken from a `DataCacheFactory` that does *not* use `DataCacheLocalCacheProperties`.

---

Note also that items in the local cache can be [evicted depending on the policies configured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790981%28v=azure.10%29.aspx):

> The lifetime of an object in the local cache is dependent on several factors, such as the maximum number of objects in the local cache and the invalidation policy.